# Unable to get updated commit on Gitlab server after push from local

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab

We are using SVN to manage code repository. Now we wanted to switch to GitLab local server. I have clone code into VS 2022 using url of my project( created on GitLab). now when I edit any cs file and try to push it shows pushed successfully but I am not able to find changes on my server files.

I got below Error

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open(".vs/test-backend-dotnet-core-project/FileContentIndex/82e25c4c-e7a4-47d5-bc45-42ab55ec8e9d.vsidx"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path .vs/test-backend-dotnet-core-project/FileContentIndex/82e25c4c-e7a4-47d5-bc45-42ab55ec8e9d.vsidx
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> When I edit any cs file and try to push it shows pushed successfully
> but I am not able to find changes on my server files. I got below
> Error
>
> "Git failed with a fatal error. error:
> open(".vs/test-backend-dotnet-core-project/FileContentIndex/82e25c4c-e7a4-47d5-bc45-42ab55ec8e9d.vsidx"):
> Permission denied"

Well, based on your description and seneario the error message indicates that you are having the error due to file access permission privilege.

There might not any direct solution for this. However, you could investigate the issue following couple of steps.

First of all,  double-check permissions, close conflicting programs, and address Git configuration concerns. Ensure your user account has write permissions to the `.vs folder` and its contents

In addition, verify ignored files and resolve conflicts if present. Retry pushing, but use force push with caution. If needed, revert local changes and try again.

Finally, you should confirm few more, configuration if those are correctly configured. For instance: make sure that,  you are using a compatible version of GitLab. Sometimes, compatibility issues can cause unexpected behavior.

In that case, consider updating your GitLab server to the latest stable version. You can use git remote -v to confirm the correct GitLab server URL is set for pushing. Also use git status to identify any untracked or conflicting files.

**Note:** Remember, switching from SVN to Git requires careful migration and understanding of Git principles. If you still want to verify the proper step, please [refer to this official document.](https://gist.github.com/leftclickben/322b7a3042cbe97ed2af)